# Is there a way to unarchive object which is being saved in userdefaults using unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData()

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class which creates an object ( two strings and one picture of NSData) on the unarchive process, I am getting a pointer. I assume this is where my object lives in memory. Which would be the most appropriate way to unarchive this already saved object from the memory.

This a project I want to make an app which by using an API you can see recipes. I am trying to make another feature where the user can upload their own recipes. since this is my first app ever I am trying to learn about data persistence.

The code seems to work fine, except the part where I need to read unarchive the data from the UserDefaults.

```
class myRecipes: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var publisher: String
    var image_url: NSData
    var title: String

    enum SerializationError:Error {
        case missing(String)
        case invalid(String, Any)
    }

    init(title: String, publisher: String, image_url: NSData) throws {
        self.publisher = publisher
        self.image_url = image_url
        self.title = title
    }

    required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let publisher = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "publisher") as! String
        let image_url = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "image_url") as! NSData
        let title = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "title") as! String
        try! self.init(title: title, publisher: publisher, image_url: image_url)

    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(publisher, forKey: "publisher")
        aCoder.encode(image_url, forKey: "image_url")
        aCoder.encode(title, forKey: "title")
    }  
}


func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let encodedData: Data = try! NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: myRecipess, requiringSecureCoding: false)
        userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "myRecipess")
        userDefaults.synchronize()
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // set the notification badge to 0.
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

        // decode the use's recipes.
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let decoded  = userDefaults.object(forKey: "myRecipess") as! Data
        let decodedTeams = try! NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(decoded) as! [myRecipes]
        print("decodedTeams")
        print(decodedTeams)
    }
```

I expect to have the data retrieved from the memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift 4 it's highly recommended to use the Codable protocol to archive data.

First of all use a struct and name it in singular form

```
struct Recipe : Codable {
    var publisher: String
    var imageUrl: Data
    var title: String
}
```

Then you have a data source array

```
var recipes = [Recipe]()
```

To save data write

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    do {
        let encodedData = try PropertyListEncoder().encode(recipes)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "recipes")
    } catch { print(error) }
}
```

To load data write

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // set the notification badge to 0.
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

    // decode the use's recipes.
    if let decoded  = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "recipes") {
       do {
          recipes = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([Recipe].self, from: decoded)
          return
       } catch { 
         print(error) 
       }
    }
    recipes = []
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried to use your code, I am getting an error on the recipes = PropertyListDecoder().decode([Recipe].self, from: decoded) saying: Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '([[Recipe]], from: Data)' which confuses me even more.

Comment: It's `[Recipe].self`, not `[[Recipe]]` and I forgot the `try` before `PropertyListDecoder()`. Answer updated.

Comment: I added the try part, I have written it the same way you have. but the error still gives the same thing. 

Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '([[Recipe]], from: Data)'

Comment: The error indicates that there are two pairs of square brackets around `Recipe`. Actually there is only **one** pair.

Comment: Would that be because the array that I am trying to store in UserDefaults is global? 
I have only one pair of square brackets around [Recipe].

Comment: Maybe, you are discouraged from declaring objects outside of any class, struct or enum. The code in the answer is supposed to work.

Comment: I manage to make it work, thank you very much for your help. 

on the struck I added an     init(title: String, publisher: String, image_url: Data) throws {
                self.publisher = publisher
                self.image_url = image_url
                self.title = title
            }

thank you for your time.

Comment: Why `throws`? This `init` method does not throw errors at all (don't you get a warning?) and in a struct you get the `init` method (without `throws`) for free. And don't use *snake_cased* variable names. The naming convention suggests *lowerCamelCased* names.